# Mobile menu button is unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5boilerplate

I am trying to build a responsive Wordpress site. [Link](http://miar.ch/fhas). I am using HTML5 Boilerplate and has been looking through Google and here for the problem.

The menu button when opening the website on iPhone iOS 7 is not responding. When zooming in via Chrome or Firefox on PC, it works perfectly well. But nothing works on whenever I open the website in Mobile Safari or Chrome. The button eventually highlights but does not open.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me if it worked on their phone or if there is a solution. Might just be a giant bug, but I can't find it :-( and I have only this smartphone so I can't test it elsewhere.

I think I have just been looking at it for too long.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you tried www.getbootstrap.com ?

Comment: You've have tried to add scripts js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js and js/main.js which do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error console in my browser there are several errors loading javascript resources for your site:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js, line 0) http://miar.ch/fhas/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap.min.js, line 0) http://miar.ch/fhas/wp-content/themes/JDK/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.8.1
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap.min.js, line 0) http://miar.ch/fhas/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (main.js, line 0) http://miar.ch/fhas/js/main.js
```

You should check these files have been correctly uploaded to your server.